# Breaking /unbreaking line in a graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have to work with an excel graph (this was already handed to me).
[image]

As you can see above the graph has a break between 2018 and 2019. I don't know how that was made. I now need to remove the break between 2018 and 2019 (this I believe I can do) and add a break between the data from 2019 and the new data for 2020. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the data for a cell that contains the value `#N/A`, or for a formula the uses the `NA()` function.

Comment: I suspect the line segment of the last point was formatted separately from the rest of the series. Click on the point that's floating out there by itself, to select the series. Then click on it again to select just the point. Now format the line segment for the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the line between markers of 2018 and 2019 is deleted. To remove the break between 2018 and 2019, you could try the following steps.

- Please select the series of line, click the marker of 2019.
- Go to Fill & Line > Line > Solid Line.

[image]

To add a break between the data from 2019 and the new data for 2020, please add the data for 2020 first. You may right click the chart > Select Data > Edit the series of line.

Then do the same as above for the marker of 2020, in addition to choose “**No line**”.

Comment: This was it exactly - thank you so much!

Comment: Elegant, simple, surprisingly easy. Never would have guessed in a million years, THANK YOU so much!